# Webpack errors when importing css

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When including css with my webpack build, i get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module parse failed:     /Users/myuser/Projects/project/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css Unexpected token (8:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  */
| /*! normalize.css v5.0.0 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
| html {
|   font-family: sans-serif;
|   line-height: 1.15;
 @ ./assets/js/index.js 33:4-47
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:3000 webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./assets/js/index
```

The offending line in my index.js is:
`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'`

My webpack.config.js looks like this: https://gist.github.com/colde/a0db7ca1a2d0a4596bc10241a6c55740

Comment: Shot in the dark, but in your CSS section, try this loader: `loader:'style!css!'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your webpack config you define the css loader as follows:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
  loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
}
```

Because bootstrap is a module you installed either from npm or bower, it is either in the `node_modules` or the `bower_compoents` directory. But you're excluding both from the loader and therefore webpack tells you that you need to configure an appropriate loader for it. Simply remove the `exclude` option to make it work correctly:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
}
```